# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/ToDoItem'

Tags: reactjs

```
const ToDoItem = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span>{text}</span>
    </li>
  );
};
export default ToDoItem;
```

I cannot understand what is wrong with the path to the file, the file extension is .js, the code editor sees the path to it, but React does not show an error

My App.js

```
import TOdoList from "./components/ToDoList";
function App() { return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <TOdoList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided, there seems to be nothing wrong with the ToDoItem component itself. The issue might be related to how you import and use this component in your main app or other components. Make sure you have correctly imported the ToDoItem component in the file where you want to use it. 

Can you provide the file structure and the file, in which you try to import this component?

Comment: Can you show us the file structure and the code snippet in the file where you import this component?

Comment: @BotondBalogh  i add my App.js into the question

Comment: @Nobunaga  i add my App.js into the question

Comment: @vitaliy125 I hope ToDoListItem.js and ToDoList.js asre present in same directory components. Whereas App.js file and components folder are siblings.